# Inbox messages for comments on answers (in iOS App) aren't behaving as expected

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, notifications, ios-app

I've noticed recently that comment notifications only link directly to the comment when that comment is on the question. Comments on answers just link to the top of the page rather than centering on the comment directly.

Here is an example:

[image: Inbox]

The top comment (from M&TV Meta) is on a question. When I select it, I get this:

[image: Question Comment Result]

As you can see, the comment is highlighted in yellow and the page is shifted down to reveal it (note that the question is not visible due to the page having auto-scrolled).

When the comment is on an answer, however, this doesn't happen. The second comment above (from ELL) is on an answer. When I select it, I get this:

[image: Answer Comment Result]

This is just the top of the question. If there's yellow highlighting it's not visible because it's off the screen. Now I have to spend a minute or two *finding* the comment. No fun!

Please fix!

Details:
Version - 1.6.0.10
iPhone 6
iOS Version - 9.3.5

Comment: Reproduced on iOS 10, same app version.

Comment: Same. I noticed this yesterday, first assumed the comment had been deleted until I happened to check the same notification on a computer.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

There were two bugs with the new link dispatcher working in unison to make this happen.  Both are fixed along with a similar issue affecting new answers.

1. I was discarding the answer information, mapping the location information to `/posts/comments/{commentId}`.
2. I was assuming that if a comment had no answer ID, it must be on the question.